# Unflattening line items in inputData when rendered by function

Tags: javascript, zapier, zapier-cli

I have dynamic children input fields that need to be rendered in a function, but when they are, then they are not included in inputData properly/not under the parent input field's key. When the children are included directly in the inputFields, it works as expected, but I can't use a function within the children array with Zapier.

Here is the inputData currently, when the line items are rendered in a function, the LI_ denotes that it is a child input key -

```
"inputData": {
    "supplier": "1",
    "LI_budget": 1,
    "LI_tax": 1,
    "company": "1",
    "currency": "1",
    "LI_price": "1",
    "LI_description": "1"
}
```

I'm expecting ("parent" is the inputField parent key here):

```
"inputData": {
    "supplier": "1",
    "parent": [{
        "LI_budget": 1,
        "LI_tax": 1,
        "LI_price": "1",
        "LI_description": "1"
     }],
    "company": "1",
    "currency": "1",
}
```

This is the function I'm using to pull in the parent and children input fields:

```
const getLineItems = async (z, bundle) => {
    let lineItem = {
        key: 'parent',
        children: [{
                key: 'LI_description',
                label: 'Description',
                required: true
            },
            {
                key: 'LI_budget',
                required: true,
                label: 'Budget',
                dynamic: 'budget.id'
            },
            {
                key: 'LI_price',
                required: true,
                type: 'number',
                label: 'Unit price',
                helpText: 'Example: 50.25'
            },

            {
                key: 'LI_tax',
                required: true,
                label: 'Tax Rate',
                dynamic: 'tax_rate.id'
            },

        ]
    }

    return [lineItem];
};
```

There are dynamic fields generated in the getLineItems function that I took out to simplify. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Caleb here from Zapier Platform Support. This is a tough one! We have a pretty long-standing issue report on our platform for supporting custom fields with `parent` keys (it boils down to a chicken vs the egg problem that really makes my head spin when I read the discussion on the issue). Your `inputFields` function is spot-on, it's just a matter of properly storing it in the bundle on our part.

I think we could cobble together a workaround to unflatten it. Before I do that though, could you give this a test in the editor and submit actual line items from a previous step to this step? I'm not sure what the `inputData` looks like (e.g. if multiple items are split like `1,2,3` or in some other fashion). If you want to iterate on this, it might be better to switch over to our public developer Slack (http://zpr.io/ttvdr); then we can post the results here for the next person to run into this.